# nginx public webdav server

Tags: nginx, pam, webdav

Can you check the user group from a $remote_user?

```
location ~ ^/dav/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/$remote_user/$1;
    auth_pam "Restricted";
    auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_access group:rw all:r;
    create_full_put_path on;
}

location ~ ^/home/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/$1;
    #check the group of the $remote_user;
}
```

curl -T test.txt 'http://gert:passwd@127.0.0.1/dav/'

curl 'http://friend:passwd@127.0.0.1/home/gert/test.txt'

Comment: Can you expand your question, what do you mean by 'select the pam user'?

Comment: I just want to prevent a user Joe to use his password to go to a different directory /home/Bart

Comment: Okay, so you might want to put that detail in the question because it's really not very clear right now.  Describe the whole problem you're trying to solve in the question.

Comment: changed the question

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables $remote_user

Comment: @GertCuykens If that solved your problem, please could you post it as an answer with a sample configuration in order to help others.

Comment: yes, but I expanded my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
location / {
    auth_pam "Restricted";
    auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
}

location ~ ^/dav/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/$remote_user/$1;
    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_access group:rw all:r;
    create_full_put_path on;
}

location ~ ^/home/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/$1;
}
```

/etc/pam.d/nginx

```
auth    required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.group
auth    required pam_unix.so
account required pam_unix.so
```

/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.group

```
home
```

curl -T test.txt 'http://gert:passwd@127.0.0.1/dav/'

curl 'http://friend:passwd@127.0.0.1/home/gert/test.txt'